# Couldn't open file: data/obj.data and /bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo

I tried to train the custom object according to https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects and I got an error.
Please tell me any good solutions.
I am going with google colaboratory.

I changed the directory, but it does not change.
dir

`--content/
 ┠darknet-master/
     ┠build/
        ┠darknet/
           ┠x64/
              ┠data/
                 ┠obj.data
                 ┠`

`%%bash
cd /content/darknet-master./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg darknet53.conv.74 > train_log.txt`

Couldn't open file: `data/obj.dat`

```
%cd /content/darknet-master/build/darknet/x64
!./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/person.jpg

/content/darknet-master/build/darknet/x64
/bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is path issue , you need to set the path.
you can use below code set path in colab.

`>import os
>os.chdir("/path/to/darknet/directory")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `%cd` or `os.chdir` rather than `%%bash cd...`

The reason is that `%%bash` run commands in a sub-shell. But, I believe what you want to do is to change the working directory of the Python backend running your code.